# How do I use CSS to style Angular Material tabs?

Tags: javascript, css, angular-material

I am very new to Angular. 
I recently added Angular Material tab in my app project similar to the one below.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"  class="firstTab"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second" class="secondTab"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"  class="thirdTab"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

In my app, I sometimes need to bring certain tabs to a user's attention. The approach I was thinking of, is by highlighting the tab of interest by giving it the below qualities:

```
.highLightTab{
   border-width: 9px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: orange;
}
```

[image]

The traditional way to achieve the above would be through

```
$(".secondTab").addClass("highLightTab");
```

However, this is proving impossible to achieve as am not able to customized CSS classes/CSS styling to any of the Mat-X elements that are generated during runtime.

Can anyone kindly tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Might want to take a look at https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Answer (score 15):

To add a custom class to your material tabs, you have to use the `ng-template` syntax:

```html
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <span class="my-custom-class">Security</span>
        </ng-template>
        Content 1
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second" class="secondTab"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab class="my-custom-class" label="Third" class="thirdTab"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

With this, you can style your `my-custom-class` as you normally would:

```css
.my-custom-class {
  border-width: 9px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}
```

You can also style default material classes by using the `::ng-deep` pseudo element.

```css
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label-active {
    border-width: 9px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: orange;
  }
```

The `:host` is optional, that scopes the styles to the tabs in the current component.

Attached is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-mat-tab-style) demo.

Comment: thank you for your posted solution, however, your solution only gives these CSS properties to the active tab `.mat-tab-label-active`, I would like to know how I can give these properties to other tabs that are NOT active `.mat-tab-label` in order to bring my user's attention to that particular tab. Would you know how to achieve this?

Comment: Ive updated the stackblitz to show how to add a custom class, I'll edit my answer to reflect this also

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend using ng-deep as it is deprecated:

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Instead, you should style it as the angular material docs:

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Since you will probably have a lot of custom styles for your material componentes, its a better aproach, and you can centralize all of the material custom styles in a single scss file if you want.

Example of a implementation (not tested, but it should work):

my-custom-elements.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@mixin custom-tabs-theme() {
  .mat-tab-label-active  {
    border-width: 9px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

global-material-theme.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

@import './material/my-custom-elements.scss';

@include custom-tabs-theme();
```

angular.json

```
...
"styles": ["src/styles.scss", "src/app/global-material-theme.scss"]
...
```

Note: You can edit any material css class this way.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but till there is an alternative to `::ng-deep` i still prefer it, avoid having to have global styles.

Comment: @Jorge Mussato thank you for your elaborate solution. Though very complex, I don't think I made my self Christal clear. I merely wanted a solution that would enable me to highlight any tab in order to bring users attention to its content. For instance, if I wanted to bring the users attention to the Third tab, I should, for instance, be able to run a similar code  `$(".thirdTab").addClass("mat-tab-label-active2");`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can do this aswell. Just set a ngClass in each tab, and in the my-custom-element.scss you add `.mat-tab-label.highlight-this` class. Also, in the html you use some kind of `[ngClass]="{highlight-this: condition}"`. This condition will make your tab highlight when you set it to true. Don't know if I made myself clear.

Comment: @C_Ogoo ::ng-deep is also a solution, but in my experience using it in a big project, things get lost and disorganized, but for smaller projects I guess it is a good alternative. I prefer not using it because its deprecated and I learned the "material docs" way