# MatSnackBar panelClass is not working from service

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my component i have a function who does that.
encapsulation is setted as "None"

```
update() {
    // do some things and then
    this.snackbarService.showSuccessToast('test success');
  }
```

snackBarService method

```
showSuccessToast(message: string, action: string = 'Close') {
    const config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
    config.horizontalPosition = 'center';
    config.duration = 200000;
    config.panelClass = ['success-snack-bar'];

    this.snackBar
      .open(message, action, config);
  }
```

And in my app.component.scss i have

```
.success-snack-bar {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

All this config it's not working.

Comment: What config is not working? Do you get an error? Or is the error that the background-color is not set on success-snack-bar element?

Comment: By "this config" i wanted to say "this component setup". The error is that the background-color is not set on success-snack-bar, and i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You define the config.panelClass but in your scss file you target the success-snack-bar element and not the class, by using `.success-snack-bar` it should work.

Comment: I'm using it as a class, it's ok. it's a typo in the question. But i've found the solution. It works for me if app.component.ts has ViewEncapsulation.None. and the ```success-snack-bar``` class in app.component.scss

Answer (score -1):

You have to `::ng-deep` for it to work.

```
::ng-deep success-snack-bar {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

Although, I don't recommend using the ng-deep, if you have a material style scss (as the material docs propose), it works the same way (without ng-deep and inside a mixin).

You can see about the mixins in this example:

[How do I use CSS to style Angular Material tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548771/how-do-i-use-css-to-style-angular-material-tabs/58549049#58549049)

Comment: ng-deep is deprecated, i can't use it.

Comment: when using ViewEncapsulation.None, ng-deep is not needed.

Comment: Did you access the link from how to substitute the ng-deep? its the same logic. I guess you didn't even read the whole answer. I did a custom mat-snackbar in the project I'm working with the custom scss file just as I proposed

Comment: @JorgeMussato, yes, i did access the link. The OP's question is not in the context of global styles but with component styles.

Comment: Ok, the correct way to style material components (i.e. mat-snackbar) is not with encapsulation nor `::ng-deep`, but if it works for you, just be careful about using those so you don't break some other styles, it already happened to me in a big project and its really bad.